# Get more items to listview without overwriting old items - Flutter

Tags: flutter, pagination, bloc

I want to make a pagination to my application using hacker news api, I want load more data when I scroll down and add new items to old items I have in the first page.

That's the code of the item page, I use a bloc pattern I wend variable named `size` to the bloc withe the event ant in the bloc I fetch only 6 items in the first load and when I scroll down I add 6 item to my loop ...

```
    class _TopPageState extends State<TopPage> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    _scrollController.addListener(() {
      if (_scrollController.position.pixels ==
          _scrollController.position.maxScrollExtent) {
        size = size + 6;
        context.read<ItemBloc>().add(GetTopEvent(size));
      }
    });
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    _scrollController.dispose();
  }

  ScrollController _scrollController = new ScrollController();
  int size = 6;
  bool isLoading = false;`enter code here`



@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {


  return Scaffold(
    body: Center(
        child: BlocBuilder<ItemBloc, ItemState>(
          builder: (context, state) {

            if (state.topState == RequestState.LOADING) {
              return const CircularProgressIndicator();
            } else if (state.topState == RequestState.ERROR) {
              print(state.errorMsg);
              return Container();
            }else if (state.topState == RequestState.NONE) {
              context.read<ItemBloc>().add(GetTopEvent(size));
              return Container();
            }
            else if (state.topState == RequestState.LOADED) {
              return NotificationListener<ScrollNotification>(
                onNotification: (notification) {
                  if (notification is ScrollUpdateNotification) {
                    _getMoreData(notification.metrics);
                  }
                  return true;
                },
                child: ListView.builder(
                    controller: _scrollController,
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 8.0),
                    itemCount: state.reposTop.length,
                    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                      return GestureDetector(
                          child: Item(state.reposTop[index]),
                          onTap: () {
                            if (state.reposTop[index].url != null) {
                              Navigator.push(
                                context,
                                MaterialPageRoute(
                                    builder: (context) =>
                                        WebViewPage(state.reposTop[index])),
                              );

                            } else if (state.reposTop[index].text != null) {
                              Navigator.push(
                                context,
                                MaterialPageRoute(
                                    builder: (context) =>
                                        ItemDetails(state.reposTop[index])),
                              );
                            }
                          });
                    }),
              );

            } else {
              return Container();
            }
          },
        ),
      ),

  );
}



void _getMoreData(ScrollMetrics metrics) {
    if (_scrollController.position.pixels ==
        _scrollController.position.minScrollExtent) {
      //&& size != 5

      if( size - 6 <=0){
        context.read<ItemBloc>().add(GetTopEvent(size));
      }
      else{
        size = size - 6;
      }
      context.read<ItemBloc>().add(GetTopEvent(size));
    }
  }
}
```